# how to get data from a table which data is not available in joined table in cakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using cakePhp 3.6, I have two table. Both are joined. In one table I have some `token` table name is `codes` and on another table I have stored some `code` for some venue. Table name is `venues_codes`.
Like I have 10 `code`in `codes` table. And in `venues_codes` table 5 `code` is stored for some vanue. 
This is the structure for `venues_codes` table.
`id venue_id code_id`.
Here `venue_id` is coming from another table. It is not my concern now. 
I just want to get the rest five `code` from `codes` table that is not available in `venues_codes` table.

This is how I have tried, but it is only fetching `token` that is available in both table.

```
$this->loadModel('VenueCodes');
$this->loadModel('Codes');
$query = $this->VenueCodes->find()
->contain(['Codes'])
->select(['id','code_id']);`
```

I am working with CakePHP. But if anyone can help me with the normal sql logic, that also will be helpful for me.

Comment: You've asked it to load VenueCodes, and include their Codes. To read all the Codes, you'd need to reverse that. Or do you mean you want to have a separate query to find the Codes that aren't already loaded?

Comment: Yes I want a separate query that will return those code that is not present in the VenueCodes table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you all the codes that are not connected to a venue:

```
$codes = $this->Codes->find()->notMatching('Venues');
```

Comment: Perfectttttttttt !. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Pure mysql query would look like this:

```
 SELECT code FROM codes WHERE code NOT IN (SELECT code_id FROM venues_codes);
```